# Yahoo finance Api not returning values

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-javascript-api, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

I was using yahoo finance api to get the stock quotes and display the contents on my site. All of a sudden from 7/november/2017 this stopped working. The url i used to get the stock quotes is https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3D%22GOOG%22&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys.

The xml does not contain values.

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks, 
Ram

Comment: See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358883/yahoo-recently-pulled-the-plug-on-their-stocks-api-what-are-yahoo-finance-rel It is also stated in the tag.

Comment: Thank you Ocaso, do you any other third party api to get the stock quotes?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

The API maybe had changed. Please check on this to get the correct API you need

[Yahoo Finance Quote console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

Something like this: [API](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yql.table.desc%20where%20name%3D%22html%22&diagnostics=true)

Hope this can help.

Comment: i tried with your suggestion and it is not working. i am getting the below mentioned result, <error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<diagnostics/>
<description>No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes</description>
</error>